# Javascript Function window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to change the line

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

to point to an API which can get a shorted Link of the actual Page.

My idea was to set it by this way

```
var url = 'http://bit.ly/api.php?url=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

and send this to Twitter

```
var twit = 'http://twitter.com/home?status='+title+'%20'+url;
```

Get the report that i have a Syntax Error but dont know which one.

Comment: Just glancing at this, shouldn't you have to encode the URL when to put it on the twit variable. Otherwise you'll have special characters on your twit string when I don't think you want them. I think you want the encodeURI(url) function.

Comment: JavaScript uses `+` for string concatenation, not `.`.

Comment: What does the second `var url` line (with the PHP in it) look like when seen in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The JavaScript concatenation operator is `+` not `.`
- `urlencode` is a PHP function, you want `encodeURIComponent`
- `$_SERVER` is a PHP superglobal, you still want `location.href`

Such:

```
var url = 'http://bit.ly/api.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href);
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin.. I got it by this way.
*** var url = 'http://bit.ly/api.php?url=' + window.location.href; ***
But Problem is that the shortning is not working on the fly.